# Why is this stack over flow article comes up on first page of google just typing 3 keywords?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, seo

[How to increase your site's position in google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

In this above article. when I entered just three keywords in google:

increase

site

position

This article comes on the first place.

Please help me understand the reasons as why only just by these three keywords?

**My observations** : I researched and observed that the phrase "increase position" have global searches of 110 (by doing phrase type search in google keyword tool) and very low competition. Does it means that the article is covering users who use increase position as a phrase to search answers for their site making them use the three keywords (increase, site, position) to ask the query.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because Google considers that page to be the most relevant result for the search phrase "increase site position". Because it ranks #1 for that search terms if you are using [Google Instant](http://www.google.com/instant/) you will see the first page appear in your browser as you type.

As for that particular page comes up first, it is a combination of keyword relevancy and link popularity/incoming link value that puts it to the top in the search results.